# how to save best weights and best model using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

Experts, I'm new to the machine learning and using Keras API with TensorFlow back-end to train a machine learning model. I'm using Model-checkpoint to save best weights and best model in .json and .h5 file independently.in so far I tried to write a code as below but i am not getting any model or weights saved. Hope i will get good solution.Thanks in advance.

```
    filepath1="best_weights.h5"
    filepath2="best_model.json"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath1, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,  mode='max')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=validation_generator, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 (at the end of your training):

You can try using the below snippet, at the end of your training to save the weights and the model architecture separately.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights("model.h5")
```

Solution 2 (during the training):

We can observe that the model architecture does not change during the training, only the weights. Therefore, you can use this checkpoint to save only the best weights during the training, and at the beginning/end of the training save only the `model_from_json`.

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath1, 
                             monitor='val_acc',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True, 
                             save_weights_only=True, 
                             mode='max')
```

> ```
> ....training runs.....
> ......................
> ....training ends.....
> ```

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

If there is nothing saved, ensure you have the correct `filepath1`.

Comment: @Thanks Timbus ....but there is error lik  name model is not defined  in the line model_json = model.to_json()

Comment: It's because you pointed it to "history" object. In your code, replace model.to_json() with history.to_json()

Comment: Additionally how to know it saved the best weights....is there any criteria to  check it...

Comment: there is Attributeerror: History object has no attribute  'to_json' while using history.to_json()

Comment: Please try not returinng history = model.fit_generator() but only model.fit_generator() and check solution 1 afterwards

Comment: Another error...tensor flow can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping....doesnot it take val_acc

Comment: Normally, on StackOverflow, when someone answers your question and it solves your problem(the initial one), you either upvote and or accept. Since it solved your problem, please accept my answer as the solving one, and if you have other questions, please ask them separately, it is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Try changing 'val_acc' to 'val_accuracy'

Comment: okkk...thanks...Aother final issue....if i change  monitor='val_acc' to monitor='val_loss' ...how to modify checkpoint...can u please suggest a solution...

Comment: You have to change to: ModelCheckpoint(filepath1, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1,save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='min')

Comment: Please accept my answer (green tick below my answer)

Comment: Thanks ...anyway i donot think it saves the best weights model....is there any routes to check it

Comment: If you leave 'verbose' = 1, it will tell you each time the val_loss is getting better.

Comment: So you will know the weights of the best model at what epochs they are.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956735/how-to-train-a-deep-learning-model-with-many-data-sets-present-inside-the-direct   if u can answer