# how to train a deep learning model with many data sets present inside the directories

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Experts i need to train a model with many data sets saved in the directories `train_data` and `valid_data`. Each data in the corresponding directories are a numpy array having rows=456 and columns 55.Additionally i have total 100 number of training data files and 20 numbers are for validation.Here each file in both directories contain data clean(data1) and data noisy(data2) in  single .npz file.Below is my generator code code but it doesn't help on  training model properly...can anybody help me on finding out where the problem lies ..

```
def tf_train_generator(file_list, batch_size = 256):
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i*batch_size >= len(file_list):  
            i = 0
            np.random.shuffle(file_list)
        else:
            file_chunk = file_list[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            print(len(file_chunk))      


            for file in file_chunk:
                print(file)
                temp = np.load(file)

               
                X = temp['data1']
               
                Y= temp['data2']  


               
                i = i + 1
                yield X, Y
```

Comment: What is your task? Image or Text, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

If it's `npz` Image-like, you can use `ImageDataGenerator` [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator). It supports both `from_directory` and `from_dataframe`.

Comment: No its the digital data not images